# Lombok EqualsAndHashCode by inner object field

Tags: java, lombok

I need to create *@EqualsAndHashCode* by the inner object field. I have two entities WorkPlace and Account.

Shortcode:

```
***WorkPlace.java***
public class WorkPlace {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    private Account account;
    .......................
}
***Account.java***
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...............
}
```

I want to create EqualsAndHashCode in WorkPlace.class using lombok like:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "account.id"})
```

When build a project - "*account.id*" ignored and created EqualsAndHashCode by ***id*** field.

Is it possible to do something like this using lombok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following method and annotation in Workplace.java to get the desired result:

```
@EqualsAndHashcode.Include
public Long getAccountId() {
  return account.getId();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I have trouble. how can I use EqualsAndHashcode.Include together with EqualsAndHashcode(of = {field names}). I have got and error:The old-style 'exclude/of' parameter cannot be used together with the new-style Include / Exclude annotations.

Comment: Get rid of the ```of = {field_name}``` and use Include annotation for all the fields you need

Comment: ... and also add `onlyExplicitlyIncluded=true`. Alternatively, exclude all fields you don't want. Feel free to reduce the visibility of `getAccountId`.